# What is the capacity of this battery (details in the body)

Tags: voltage, batteries, current-measurement, capacity, alkaline

Can someone give me the capacity (in Ah) for [this battery?](https://www.amazon.in/Voltage-Battery-23AE-C5-Alkaline-Batteries/dp/B07PH3N2X7/ref=asc_df_B07PH3N2X7/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397083563249&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=18234134172202885821&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007811&hvtargid=pla-836725096759&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi)

[image]

Comment: [This](https://panda-bg.com/datasheet/1622-360803-Battery-GP-ULTRA-ALKALINE-23AE-12V.pdf) may be the datasheet. Just read it. The packaging is mostly just a lot of "buy me hype." (No added lead mostly means nothing. Their suppliers may do all that nasty work, if needed. And the 0% mercury just means it is less than 0.5%, at least in the US packaging rules I'm vaguely aware of. They aren't advertising the meat. They are selling the sizzle.) Compare it with some other competing devices that also have datasheets. And even then, you probably have no recourse if the device doesn't do what they say.

Comment: Thanks you Jonk.

Comment: Be aware that the ratings include a voltage that almost immediately drops from 12 V down to 6 V before they consider the battery "dead." Whatever you use them for, make sure that the device works well with them over such a wide voltage range. These batteries are basically about 9 V and they cannot stand much of a load unless you want them to get used up pretty fast. The capacity drops to < 50% of the rating, under high load.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you.

Comment: I hope you aren't expecting this battery to power the solenoid in your other question.